# Axon- Replay event for a particular type or for one particular Id

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

Using Axon framework- I was able to replay the entire event store and re-create the view model. But is it possible to replay event for a particular type or for a particular Id.

Let's say, I have a customer event and I want to replay all the event of a customer with Id= 100. Is it make sense to do a replay for a particular customer or it make more sense to replay for the entire event store always?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to do whatever makes sense for you, for this particular ReadModel.

One reason to re-process only one customer is the speed. If it's a lot faster than a complete rebuild (i.e because you have a lot of customers) and *the outcome is the same* then do it.

Answer (score 0):

As Constantin points out, this request to replay a specific view makes total sense.

The provided replay process in Axon Framework at this point only provides to trigger a replay for a specific Processing Group allowing you to set the point in time from when you want to replay it.

There are ideas to provide a more fine grained solution to replaying, I'd however be hard pressed to tell you when that'll happen.
Thus replaying just a single view model for, for example speed, will require some custom code. 
Let me know if you'd be interested in some pointers on how to do that.

---

**Update**

I'd like to state that with more recent versions of Axon Framework is is possible to tell a `TrackingEventProcessor` to reset itself, thus replay a set of events.
The API for this is the `TrackingEventProcessor#resetTokens(TrackingToken)`, which allows you to reset a Tracking Event Processor from a given point in time.

This still doesn't give you the option to replay a given instance of a Read Model. This would still require some handy work from your part.